# Which free native XML database is most popular?

Tags: xml, database

If I asked about most popular free relational database I'd expect to get MySQL or PostgreSQL or perhaps SQLite.

But what about native XML databases? Which is most popular and stable? Did you use one in some of your projects? Which one? Which one would you advise for personal medium sized project?

Comment: *(reference)* [Native XML Databases - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_database#Native_XML_databases)

Comment: As a completely off-topic comment, I'm going to take a close look at http://persvr.org/ which is JSON (sqlite-like) database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used [eXist](http://exist.sourceforge.net/). I'm not claiming that this is the best and most popular XML database, but it was OK for my purposes. It's simple to install and configure. It's opensource, it supports XQuery, XPath, and (what was really useful for my project) it has nice and simple SOAP and REST APIs. I agree with the comment above that XML databases are not really a good idea for large storages.

Answer (score 10):

Our company uses [eXist](http://exist-db.org) extensively for our DITA content management system.

The product is very good. Includes full XQuery support, efficient xml indexing and a good application layer to build things off of.

As per previous comments, the notion that Native XML databases are a fad is not really representational of the market ither. In fact in terms of NoSQL products, MarkLogic server (a native XML database) blows away nearly every other SQL database in terms of performance, especially related to document-centric search. Its being used very extensivly in some of the most performance critical applications of some very big companies. (Its also very expensive!)

I won't go into the XML vs JSON thing here too much because its not worth it. However, from a storage standpoint xml vs json is not really a relevant argument. All databases essentially normalize the information down to very efficinet stores. However XML is a very solid standard that is backed with many powerful technologies.

- XPath (parent or ancestor selection anyone?)
- XQuery
- XSLT
- XML Schema
- XProc
- XMLDB
- Namespacing

If you have a specific need for JSON then its a good idea to investigate a JSON database. Just be aware that XML really isn't a fad, and is a very solid framework when working with document centric data.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [BaseX](http://basex.org).

Specially if you want to work with clients, there is [documentation](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Clients). for many languages, including e.g. scriting for [PHP](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/tree/master/basex-api/src/main/php).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java, I would recommend BaseX rather than eXist.
It it easier to use and has much better query speed out of the box.

Otherwise Berkeley DB XML I am good engine, but embeddable/C++ so less easy to integrate.

Answer (score -1):

I think they were a fad and none are really popular now. XML is good for data exchange but not that great for large data storage.

Comment: Should have been a comment, but really is most likely the best answer to this. XML has a lot of bad. Difficult to process, bulky,and several other things... JSON is a much nicer format and if you're going with NoSQL then you might as well go with something that isn't XML.. I personally like MongoDB

Comment: I'm asking because I mostly deal with tree-like data and enjoy XPath very much so I'd like to have such power in my queries.

Comment: XML databases are certainly not a fad, if anything they are becoming more popular than structured databases for working with document style data. Like webpages, documentation etc. Structured databases have a really hard time compeating with the efficiencies a Native XML database offers in this realm